# How it is possible to make background transparent when secont text animate?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to make a typography animation where I want to animate the second text which is colored and also it has multiple text to animate. In this animation, I want to show and hide the text one after the other with a cursor-moving effect. But in this, I have an issue to make the background transparent, because in the background I want to run the video also, so it is compulsory to make the span's background transparent so that it looks permanently hidden

```js
const text = document.querySelector(".sec-text");
        const textLoad = () => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                text.textContent = "Real Estate";
            }, 0);
            setTimeout(() => {
                text.textContent = "The Best Deal";
            }, 4000);
        }
        textLoad();
        setInterval(textLoad, 8000);
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;300;400;500;600&display=swap');
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
body{
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background: #010718;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.container{
    width: 360px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.container .text{
    position: relative;
    color: #c32000;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 600;
}
.container .text.first-text{
    color: #FFF;
}
.text.sec-text:before{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #010718;
    border-left: 2px solid #c32000;
    animation: animate 4s steps(8) infinite;
}
@keyframes animate{
    40%, 60%{
        left: calc(100% + 4px);
    }
    100%{
        left: 0%;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="textAnim.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <span class="text first-text">Absolute</span>
        <span class="text sec-text"></span>
    </div>


  
</body>
</html>
```

.

Answer (score 1):

You could just animate the text itself:

```js
const delay = () => new Promise(r=>setTimeout(()=>requestAnimationFrame(r), 100));

const text = document.querySelector(".sec-text");

const animate = async str => {
  
  for(const char of str){
    text.textContent += char;
    await delay();
  }
  await new Promise(r=>setTimeout(r, 1000));
  let less = str;
  do{
    less = less.slice(0, less.length - 1)
    text.textContent = less;
    await delay();
  }while(less);
  
}

(async () => {
  const arr = ['Real Estate', 'The Best Deal', 'Support 24/7'];
  let idx = 0;
  while(true){
    await animate(arr[idx++]);
    if(idx === arr.length){
      idx = 0;
    }
  }
  
})();
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;300;400;500;600&display=swap');
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
body{
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background: #010718;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.container{
    width: 360px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.container .text{
    position: relative;
    color: #c32000;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 600;
}
.container .text.first-text{
    color: #FFF;
}

.text.sec-text:after{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: -5px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #010718;
    border-left: 2px solid #c32000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="textAnim.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <span class="text first-text">Absolute</span>
        <span class="text sec-text"></span>
    </div>


  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I like this. The added delay when the typing is done was the only thing missing.

Comment: @shivanisrivastav you are welcome. you forgot to accept my answer (the checkbox) and upvote it (the arrow up). that way i'll be rewarded and motivated to help you in the future. that's how stackoverflow works, thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is what I managed to do. The idea is to vary the width of the box containing the red text. So there's nothing to cover up because the text will be hidden when it overflows the width of the box.

```js
const text = document.querySelector(".sec-text");
        const textLoad = () => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                text.textContent = "Real Estate";
            }, 0);
            setTimeout(() => {
                text.textContent = "The Best Deal";
            }, 5000);
        }
        textLoad();
        setInterval(textLoad, 10000);
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;300;400;500;600&display=swap');
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
body{
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background: #010718;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.container{
    width: 360px;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: #FFF;
}
.container .text{
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.text.sec-text{
    color: #c32000;
    border-right: 2px solid #c32000;
    animation: animate 5s steps(10) infinite; 
}
@keyframes animate{
    0%, 10%, 100%{
        width: 0px;
    }
    45%, 70%{
        width: 220px;
    }
}
```

```html
    <div class="container">
        <span class="text first-text">Absolute</span>
        <span class="text sec-text"></span>
    </div>
```

It's not perfect because the two red texts don't have the same length and the animation ignores that, but I think it still looks pretty good.